# OpenSSL with Apache Tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, ssl, openssl

I use Tomcat with native extensions, so it is necessary to use OpenSSL for making certificates.

Does anyone know how to make a certificate with OpenSSL and install it into Tomcat?

Comment: I think there's a FAQ on it on Apache's tomcat website.

Comment: and a couple others when you google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. You use the same keystore regardless what SSL libraries you use. I have been using the same keystore for several Tomcat instances. Some of them uses APR.

If you are familiar with keytool, you can create certificate with keytool and it just works fine with OpenSSL.

Comment: You are right. All I need to do was to convert my java keystore to a PEM file. First I converted my java keystore to a PKCS-12 file, which I could convert to a PEM file with OpenSSL.